# C++: Passing lambda pointer as a function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, function-pointers

I want to get values of an implicit function in C++. For simplicity let's say that I am interested in the function is x(a) which is defined by x*x - a == 0.

I have a root finder that uses Brent's method which is declared as

```
BrentsFindRoot( double (*f)(double), double a, double b, double tol )
```

Since the first argument is a pointer to a function double -> double, I thought I could accomplice that by using lambda functions. So I defined

```
auto Foo(double a) {
    auto f = [a] (double x) noexcept -> double {
        return x*x - a;
    };
    return f;
}
```

and I thought I could get `sqrt(2)` by calling `BrentsFindRoot(&Foo(2),0,10,1e-10)`. However, the compiler complains that it cannot cast a lambda function to a function pointer. I read that this can be done only if the lambda function does not capture anything, but in my case it needs to capture `a`.

So what is the solution here? Is there any way to pass `Foo(2)` to `BrentsFindRoot`? Or alternatively how can I redeclare `BrentsFindRoot` so that it accepts lambda functions?

I am using C++17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BrentsFindRoot` takes a stateless function pointer.

Your lambda has state.

These are not compatible.  Both conceptually and syntactically.

```
BrentsFindRoot( double (*f)(void const*, double), void const*, double a, double b, double tol )
```

this is how the signature would change if you added state and wanted it to remain a pure C function.  Then passing a lambda works conceptually, but the syntax is awkward. If you do not mind C++ in your root finder:

```
BrentsFindRoot( std::function<double(double)> f, double a, double b, double tol )
```

Alternatively, you can shoe-horn state into a stateless function pointer via table/global state tricks.  You could also make the lambda stateless by taking and storing something equivalent to `a` as a compile time parameter.

But just do the `std::function` version.

if `BrentsFindRoot` is a header only function, you can use a template

```
template<class F>
void BrentsFindRoot( F f, double, double, double );
```

a final option is to find or write a `function_view` type; this can be more efficient than a `std::function` by avoiding storage.

```
union function_state {
  void* pvoid;
  void(* pfvoid)();
  function_state(void* p=nullptr):pvoid(p) {}
  template<class R, class...Args>
  function_state(R(*pf)(Args...)):pfvoid(reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(pf)) {}
};
template<class Sig>
struct function_view;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_view<R(Args...)> {
  function_state state;
  R(*pf)(function_state, Args&&...args) = nullptr;

  R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return pf(state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  function_view(function_view const&)=default;
  function_view& operator=(function_view const&)=default;
  explicit operator bool() const{ return pf; }

  function_view( R(*f)(Args...) ):
    state(f),
    pf([](function_state s, Args&&...args)->R{
      return reinterpret_cast<R(*)(Args...)>(s.pfvoid)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    })
  {}


  template<class F, std::convertible_to<R> FR=std::invoke_result_t< F, Args... >>
  requires (!std::is_same_v<R,void>)
  function_view( F&& f ):
    state((void*)std::addressof(f)),
    pf([](function_state s, Args&&...args)->R{
      return (*static_cast<F*>(s.pvoid))( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    })
  {}
  template<class F>
  requires (std::is_same_v<R, void>)
  function_view( F&& f ):
    state((void*)std::addressof(f)),
    pf([](function_state s, Args&&...args)->void{
      (*static_cast<F*>(s.pvoid))( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    })
  {}


  template<std::convertible_to<R> R0, std::constructible_from<Args>...As>
  requires (!std::is_same_v<R,void>)
  function_view( R0(*f)(As...) ):
    state(f),
    pf([](function_state s, Args&&...args)->R{
      return reinterpret_cast<R0(*)(As...)>(s.pfvoid)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    })
  {}
  template<class R0, std::constructible_from<Args>...As>
  requires (std::is_same_v<R, void>)
  function_view( R0(*f)(As...) ):
    state(f),
    pf([](function_state s, Args&&...args)->void{
      reinterpret_cast<R0(*)(As...)>(s.pfvoid)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    })
  {}
};
```

but that probably isn't something you want to write quite yet.

Comment: maybe also worth mentioning that the lambda is not a function, but an object with an `operator()`, and only considering that passing a pointer to the lambda was the wrong path to take

Comment: @4603 If the C API was the one above, you'd end up passing a pointer to lambda plus a wrapping lambda for `f`.  I am not that interested in teaching C++ type names and terms, as useful as it is to know.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a function pointer or `std::function`, you can use a template too:

```
template<class Callback>
void BrentsFindRoot(Callback const& f, double a, double b, double tol ) {
    // ...
}
```